# Testing hypothesis using Extra Sum of Squares (F-Test)

Tags: statistics, regression, hypothesis-testing

The full model is given by $E(Y_i\mid x)=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{i1}+\beta_2 x_{i2} + \beta_3 x_{i3}$

Test the hypothesis that $E(Y_i\mid x)=x_{i1}$ is a good model.

> I calculated the FULL Residual SS to be $RSS_{f}=0.765$
>
> The Simple Residual SS is $RSS_s=1689.21$

Now I was to test that $\beta_0=\beta_2=\beta_3=0$ and $\beta_1=1$

My notes suggest to put it in the form $C\beta=d$ where $C$ is $c\times 4$ matrix.

Then I can do an F-test: $$f=\frac{(RSS_s-RSS_f)/c}{RSS_f/(n-4)}$$

Can somebody help me with building the $C\beta=d$ part? What is the value of $c$? Intuitively I think it's $c=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$c$ should be the number of restrictions or equivalently the difference between the "degrees of freedom" between the unrestricted and restricted model. In your case, $c=4-0=4$ (you have "restrictions" on all the $4$ regression coefficients). Formally,

$$
F=\frac{(C\hat{\beta} - d)'(C(X'X)^{-1}C')^{-1}(C\hat{\beta} - d)/c}{e'e/(n-p)}. 
$$
For your case you have $C=I$ and $d=(0,1,0,0)'$, thus $c=4$ and after some algebra you get the form of
$$
F = \frac{(RSS_r - RSS_f)/4}{RSS_f/(n-4)}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, what would $C\beta=d$ be? Is $C=I$ and $\beta=d=(0,1,0,0)^T$?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit my answer a little later to fit the matrix form notation. By the way, if it is OK to ask - what kind of textbook are you using? To the best of my knowledge, these notations style are not that common in the classical stat. books.

Comment: I'm using notes which have the following references: Montgomery, D.C & Peck, Introduction to Linear Regression Analysis 2nd Edition. 2) Weisberg, Applied LInear Regression, 3rd Edition, Wiley, 2005 3)Krzanowski, W., An Introduction to statistical Modelling, Arnold, 1998. Would you like a copy of the notes?

Comment: It will be interesting to take a look at. Is it available on some online server?

Comment: Here the are: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4hDcTPeFihWV1dsbUFwdmtHSjA